# How can I get the number of Apple Silicon performance cores in Python?

Tags: python, cpu, apple-silicon, sysctl

I want to determine the number of performance cores in a Python script (it's actually going to be a Python app frozen with PyInstaller, if that makes a difference).

There are some ways to get the number of CPUs/cores like `os.cpu_count()`, `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` or `psutil.cpu_count()` (the latter allowing discrimination between physical and virtual cores). However, Apple Silicon CPUs are separated into performance and efficiency cores, which you can get with (e.g.) `sysctl hw.perflevel0.logicalcpu_max` for performance and `sysctl hw.perflevel1.logicalcpu_max` for efficiency cores.

Is there any way to get this in Python besides running `sysctl` and get the shell output?

Comment: But there is the module `pyobjc`, which contains a lot of tools. Maybe there’s sth. of use in it?

Comment: @Codist: It's not unique to Apple!  ARM has had big.LITTLE heterogeneous CPUs since 2011, long before Apple M1, perhaps before Apple did it in their in-house iphone CPUs.  Also, Intel has been doing it since Alder Lake ([What are performance and efficiency cores in Intel's 12th Generation Alder lake CPU Line?](https://superuser.com/q/1677692)), and AMD is planning it, too. (Although in AMD's case, it's just different amounts of cache for a Zen4c core.)  Anyway it is still pretty new to desktop/laptop OSes (unlike Android / iPhone) so portable APIs aren't really established yet in most things.